# How to implement On behalf of flow in Azure Ad?

Tags: azure, asp.net-core, authentication, azure-active-directory, jwt

Net core application. I have three applications registered in azure ad.

1. React SPA application
2. Web API Gateway application
3. Protected API application

Whenever user logs into SPA application, Redirecting to Azure AD with implicit flow to get access token.
I have received access token as below and used to access apis from gateway layer

```
{
  "aud": "7851c317b-87e7-4cb3-95f0-37cb52b6f873",
  "family_name": "alex",
  "given_name": "fernandes",
  "hasgroups": "true",
  "roles": [
      "Admin"
  ]
}
```

In the above token aud is client id of the spa application and other few details I added but not all the details.

Now I want to call Protected API application from Web API Gateway application

I am trying with sample http request in postman as below.

Request - https://login.microsoftonline.com/45fgh-f30d-4596-gt67-7045b338485a/oauth2/v2.0/token

Body

```
{
"grant_type": "urn:ietf:params:oauth:grant-type:jwt-bearer"
"client_id": "" //unknown client id of SPA or API GateWay or Protected API
"client_secret": "" //unknown client id of SPA or API GateWay or Protected API
"assertion": "Above token"
"scope":"" //unknown
"requested_token_use" : "on_behalf_of"
}
```

Along with above confusions, just wondering Is there any configurations required in azure ad in order to generate token for Protected API. One more thing is the token generated to access Protected API does that token have user details and role details same as above token generated by SPA?

Can someone help me in configuring On behalf of flow? I am struggling here to get this done. Any help would be appreciated. Thank you

Answer (score 4):

As the following diagram shows, Client App means React SPA application, Web API 1 means Web API Gateway application, and Web API 2 means Protected API application. For more details, see [this blog](https://blogs.aaddevsup.xyz/2019/08/understanding-azure-ads-on-behalf-of-flow-aka-obo-flow/).

[image]

**Steps of On-Behalf-Of flow:**

1. Add API permission of Web API Gateway application to SPA application.

[image]

```
GET https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant}/oauth2/v2.0/authorize
?scope={permission for Web API Gateway application like api://1108f6-xxxxxxx-9f622/test} openid
&redirect_uri={redirect_uri of SPA application}
&nonce=123
&client_id={client-id of SPA application}
&response_type=id_token token
```

2. Add API permission of Protected API application to Web API Gateway application.

It calls Microsoft Graph API in the official [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-on-behalf-of-flow), so the scope is 'user.read' in this step.

```
POST https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant}/oauth2/v2.0/token
grant_type=urn:ietf:params:oauth:grant-type:jwt-bearer
&client_id={client_id of Web API Gateway application}
&client_secret={client_secret}
&assertion={access token from previous step}
&scope={permission for Protected API application}
&requested_token_use=on_behalf_of
```

3. Call Protected API application with the access token

Comment: Hi Pamela Thanks for your answer. It will really help me.  I have some points to ask.  Above in the second step to get token, we have to pass client id, client secrete and assertion. I tried with as above. The error message what it says is aud in token(recieved from spa) and client id passed in step 2 should be same. But in my token recieved from SPA client is client id of SPA application registered in azure AD.

Comment: Second question, If I am able to successfully able to generate token in step2, then will I get all the roles in the token because when I generate token in step1 for SPA I have groups and roles associated to it. In my protected API all business logic runs based on roles. So I want same roles in token. Will this happen? Can you pls help me to understand the concepts here and help me to achieve this. Thanks

Comment: Have you tried the code? In the step1, the scope is `api://{client-id of Web API Gateway application}/{scope-name}`, and it responses `aud` as `api://{client-id of Web API Gateway application}`.

Comment: On the second question, in theory, you sign in with the same account in steps, and the roles should be the same. If you mean the permissions, they are related to the scope you set.

Comment: Hi Pamela. currently I have app roles assigned to my gateway app. In first token I am able to get roles. When I request second token that is gateway app to protected app I wont get app roles in token. This is because app roles are not there in protected api. My requirement is to get app roles in second token also. does this mean I should add app roles for 2 applications? one for gatewap and one for protected api?